# Contradictory results in testing convergence of improper integral

Tags: real-analysis, integration, convergence-divergence, definite-integrals, improper-integrals

I was testing the convergence of the integral $$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{1+2\sqrt x+x^2}dx$$ by calculating the limit $$\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{1+2\sqrt{x}+x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}}=1>0$$ and by noting that $$\int_0^{+\infty}\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}=+\infty$$ therefore the original integral has to be divergent as well. However Mathematica seems to evaluate the original integral to 2.04517. What is wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The limit you have found
$$
\lim_{x\to+\infty}\frac{\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{1+2\sqrt{x}+x^2}}{\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}}=1
$$ implies that, as $x \to \infty$,
$$
\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{1+2\sqrt{x}+x^2}\sim{\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}}
$$

you **can't deduce** it holds as $x \to 0$. Therefore, we have that, for any large fixed $B>0$, 
$$
\int_B^\infty\frac{\sqrt{x+1}}{1+2\sqrt{x}+x^2}\:dx, \quad\int_B^\infty {\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}}\:dx,
$$ are **both convergent**. Observe that the integrand $\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}}{1+2\sqrt{x}+x^2}$ is a continuous function as $x \to 0^+$, giving the convergence of the initial integral over $(0,\infty)$.

Comment: Doesn't $B$ have to be $\ge 1$ to deduce convergence for both of them, since the integral we're comparing to converges only for $B\ge 1$ ?

Comment: @ahra Not really, the integral $\int_B^\infty {\frac{1}{x^{3/2}}}\:dx$ converges for any $B>0$. Thus $B\ge1$ is fine, but necessary.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!